# AKS throwing unkown 404 /healthz repeatedly

Tags: kubernetes, http-status-code-404, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

We just updated our AKS version and updated all related files.
Now I get 404 from unknown source:

```
http://10.116.180.68:31212/healthz  
http://100.78.4.224:31212/healthz   
http://100.92.120.255:31212/healthz
```

Ips in start change randomly and path at the end in `/heathz`.

My app is deployed on Azure Aks, and application is in .NET Core.

[image]

My application insights also attached.

Not find any way to figure out issue or solution.

```
kubectl describe pod


Name:             kubernetes-dashboard----------k7hpn
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  kubernetes-dashboard
Node:             aks-default-31477792-vmss000009/10.240.0.6
Start Time:       Sat, 29 Oct 2022 07:39:14 +0000
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/component=kubernetes-dashboard
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=kubernetes-dashboard
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=kubernetes-dashboard
                  app.kubernetes.io/version=2.3.1
                  helm.sh/chart=kubernetes-dashboard-5.0.0
                  pod-template-hash=------------
Annotations:      seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default
Status:           Running
IP:               ------
IPs:
  IP:           -------
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/kubernetes-dashboard--------------------
Containers:
  kubernetes-dashboard:
    Container ID:  containerd://-----------------------------------
    Image:         kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.3.1
    Image ID:      docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard@sha256:---------------------------------------
    Port:          8443/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --namespace=default
      --auto-generate-certificates
      --token-ttl=0
      --metrics-provider=none
      --enable-skip-login
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sat, 29 Oct 2022 07:39:30 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  200Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     200Mi
    Liveness:     http-get https://:8443/ delay=30s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /certs from kubernetes-dashboard-certs (rw)
      /tmp from tmp-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-b47x4 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kubernetes-dashboard-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  kubernetes-dashboard-certs
    Optional:    false
  tmp-volume:
```

**Ingress Service Code**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: -----------------p
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app-stage
    secretName: -----------
  rules:
    http:
      paths:
      - path:  /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Release.Name }}-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
---
```

logs from ** kubectl logs -n stagging ingress-nginx-controller-adfahoiy234345 **

```
10.244.5.1 - - [07/Nov/2022:10:01:48 +0000] "GET /healthz HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 171 0.002 [stagging-ezymigrate-shared-frontend-api-service-80] [] 10.244.7.23:8080 0 0.004 404 85a030bb23f790ab35f6e6cb6e11f470
10.240.0.4 - - [07/Nov/2022:10:01:49 +0000] "GET /healthz HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 175 0.002 [stagging-ezymigrate-shared-frontend-api-service-80] [] 10.244.7.23:8080 0 0.000 404 ae39a964fa99874d81e4c3e34e391baa
10.240.0.7 - - [07/Nov/2022:10:01:49 +0000] "GET /healthz HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 175 0.003 [stagging-ezymigrate-shared-frontend-api-service-80] [] 10.244.7.23:8080 0 0.000 404 631a1fee6582c6d1113541b001eefffc
10.240.0.6 - - [07/Nov/2022:10:01:52 +0000] "GET /healthz HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 175 0.002 [stagging-ezymigrate-shared-frontend-api-service-80] [] 10.244.7.23:8080 0 0.000 404 e38e5d00119d63e55616dcc36221b668
10.240.0.9 - - [07/Nov/2022:10:01:52 +0000] "GET /healthz HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 173 0.003 [stagging-ezymigrate-shared-frontend-api-service-80] [] 10.244.7.23:8080 0 0.004 404 8ccc7ce16cab68ba15eee5c217617651
10.240.0.8 - - [07/Nov/2022:10:01:52 +0000] "GET /healthz HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 171 0.002 [stagging-ezymigrate-shared-frontend-api-service-80] [] 10.244.7.23:8080 0 0.000 404 cebf955c53be881cea7c310a8de1d2c7
10.244.5.1 - - [07/Nov/2022:10:01:53 +0000] "GET /healthz HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 171 0.003 [stagging-ezymigrate-shared-frontend-api-service-80] [] 10.244.7.23:8080 0 0.004 404 ee552ce8cf8d34f5799ad9c0b419c91d
10.240.0.4 - - [07/Nov/2022:10:01:54 +0000] "GET /healthz HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 175 0.002 [stagging-ezymigrate-shared-frontend-api-service-80] [] 10.244.7.23:8080 0 0.004 404 dbf0121c64ea3225cce3dfa5e4b97ebb
10.240.0.7 - - [07/Nov/2022:10:01:55 +0000] "GET /healthz HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 175 0.002 [stagging-ezymigrate-shared-frontend-api-service-80] [] 10.244.7.23:8080 0 0.004 404 291838b5d832f04485ed3d7f5b89e9e7
```

Comment: seems like the issue is from ingress, can also post ingress logs? or `kubectl describe pod <ingress-contorller-pod>`

Comment: or may be its default backend, but without ingress logs its hard to say anything https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/

Comment: @Adiii
[07:49:06 Information] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware
HTTP GET /healthz responded 404 in 0.0367 ms

[07:49:06 Information] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware
HTTP GET /healthz responded 404 in 0.0712 ms

Same Error repeat in logs

Comment: @Adiii Code description Updated ....

Comment: the logs should be from the ingress, not from the dashboard

Comment: @Adiii I have Update Logs with Ingress\service file

Answer (score 0):

`/healthz` is the default health probe path for ingress controller service and other LoadBalancer type of services in an AKS cluster. The requests should be coming from the LoadBalancer to determine if the backend of that service is healthy or not.

The reason these 404 responses appear is because, by default, the request to `/healthz` is supposed to be handled by the ingress controller pod itself. see this doc: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/

But if you use wildcard (*) in your ingress rules, the request to health probe will be catched by your ingress rule and processed by backend pod specified in the ingress rule. And if your backend pod does not have `/healthz` defined, it'll return 404.

Another possible reason is that, if the `externalTrafficPolicy` of your service is set to `Local`, then only nodes that the ingress controller pod runs on can respond to that request correctly, other nodes will respond with HTTP 404.